# jQuery post redirects to get

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, ajax

I have a simple ajax method in my MVC.Net project which adds entries to a calendar, but when I run the following code:

```
 sDate = new Date(jQuery(".datepicker").val());
 var args = {  startdate: date.toDateString(), starttime: jQuery('#ddlFrom').val(), endtime: jQuery('#ddlTo').val() };
 var action = "/EventController/AddEvent/";

            jQuery.post(action, args,
                function (response) {
                    console.log(response);
                    if (response == "") {
                        jQuery('#js_divSuccess').show();
                    } else {
                        jQuery('#divError').text(response);
                    }
                });
```

It first does the following (looking in firebug):

[image: Wierd redirect]

Why does it make a redirect on a post?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must accidentally have the redirect (instead of forward) in that controller API on the server-side.

Comment: I am used to webforms, and had a response.redirect on my serverside which caused the problem. Thanks!